# Default argument determining type of generic method

Tags: typescript, generics, default-arguments, typescript-generics

I defined a generic method whose generic type is determined by one of the arguments:

```
myMethod<T>(param1: number, param2: T): T {
  return param2;
}
```

Now, I'd like to have a default value for the parameter, and T would then be determined by the type of the default value:

```
myMethod<T>(param1: number, param2: T = 'myDefaultString'): T {
  return param2;
}
```

But that does not compile, because it expects "string" to match T instead of determining T to be 'string'.

One solution would be to write:

```
myMethod<T>(param1: number, param2: T = <any>'myDefaultString'): T {
  return param2;
}
```

But then I need to specify the type explicitly at the calling site:

```
const val: string = this.myMethod<string>();
```

Another solution I considered was to write a second function, without the default argument:

```
myMethod<T>(param1: number, param2: T): T {
  return param2;
}

myMethodDefault(param1: number): string {
  return myMethod(param1, 'myDefaultString');
}
```

But then I need a different name for it, and that bothers me.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

The type part can be fulfilled with a default generic type parameter (since TypeScript 2.3):

```
class Hey {
    myMethod<T = string>(arg1: number, arg2?: T): T {
        if (arg2 === undefined)
            // have to handle default parameter manually
            return "myDefaultString" as any as T;
        return arg2;
    }
}

const h = new Hey();

// n1: string;
const n1 = h.myMethod(1);
// n2: typeof "mm"
const n2 = h.myMethod(2, "mm");
// n3: { a: number }
const n3 = h.myMethod(3, { a: 1 });
```

Comment: Very interesting. One drawback I see is that the string type is defined in 2 places (the default value and the default type). If they don't match, I believe we could have problems because type checking would be on the default type, while at runtime the default value would have another type.

Answer (score 2):

```
myMethod<T>(param1: number, param2: T = 'myDefaultString'): T {
  return param2;
}
```

The above code is indeed invalid, because the expression `inst.myMethod<number>(23)` would have the type `number`, while still being a `string` at runtime.

You can work around this by using signature overloads:

```
// with only one param, the return type is a string:
myMethod(param1: number): string
// with two params, use a type parameter:
myMethod<T>(param1: number, param2: T): T
myMethod(param1: number, param2: any = 'myDefaultString') {
  return param2;
}
```

This version makes `inst.myMethod<number>(23)` invalid, because the signature with a type param requires a second parameter.

Answer (score -4):

You are right, I don't think there is a way to do this without putting unnecessary complication into your class. You would check the type inside and then return a default just in a specific situation. However, I don't think such check is a good pattern as well.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p2 = "test";
        var p3 = 23;
        Console.WriteLine(myMethod<string>(0, p2));
        Console.WriteLine(myMethod<int>(0, p3));
        Console.WriteLine(myMethod(0, p2));
        Console.WriteLine(myMethod(0, p3));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static public T myMethod<T>(int param1, T param2) 
    {
        return param2;
    }

    static public string myMethod(int param1, string param2)
    {
        return param2;
    }
```

Comment: This isn't TypeScript?!